# Question is Find the 2nd largest digit ,What is wrong with my code, I am a beginner

Tags: python, digits

Question is   Find the 2nd largest digit ,What is wrong with my code, I am a beginner ,Output is still zero

```
a = input("Enter your number")
max = 0
maxx  = 0

list1 = []


for i in a :
    list1.append(i)
    if i > str(max) :
        max = i
        list1.remove(max)
        for j in list1 :
            if j > str(maxx) :
            maxx = j
print(maxx)
```

Comment: The line below the first `if` statement isn't indented correctly. Are you sure your code is indented right?

Comment: Just a tip, you shouldn't make a variable called `max` - it's a builtin function

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The second `for` loop shouldn't have been nested and inside a conditional like that, since it would only run until the highest number was found.

The other main issue is that that even without the second `for` loop being nested, in a situation where `a = '12345'` every number is the highest the first loop finds and is therefore deleted from `list1` meaning that `list1` ends up completely empty.

This should work:

```
a = input("Enter your number: ")
max_num = 0
maxx  = 0


for i in a :
    if i > str(max_num) :
        max_num = i
        
for j in a :
    if j > str(maxx) and j < str(max_num):
        maxx = j
        
print(maxx)
```

or you can also do this:

```
nums = input('Enter numbers: ')
list1 = []

for i in nums:
    list1.append(int(i))
    
list1.sort()
print(list1[-2])
```

Comment: Isn't sorting O(nlogn), which is unnecessarily slow?